# How do I print quotations (") with Console.Writeline?

Tags: vb.net

`Console.WriteLine("Text here")` prints `Text here` on the Console.

But, how do I print `I thought "Was I doing it correctly?"`?

The quotations would be considered as the end of the expression, and thus, it is not possible to print quotations using `Console.WriteLine`.
Is there any work-around to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.NET, you can print double quotes as such: `"""" -> "`.
So, each `""` in the source literal becomes one double quote in the output.

Answer (score 1):

changing `"` to `""`:

```
Console.WriteLine("I thought ""Was I doing it correctly?""")
```

Answer (score 0):

Three options:

1 - Escape the string with additional double quotes:

```
Console.WriteLine("I thought ""Was I doing it correctly?""")
```

2 - Use `Chr(34)` from the `VisualBasic` namespace:

```
Console.WriteLine("I thought {0}Was I doing it correctly?{0}", Microsoft.VisualBasic.Chr(34))
```

3 - Use `Convert.ToChar(34)`:

```
Console.WriteLine("I thought {0}Was I doing it correctly?{0}", Convert.ToChar(34))`
```

Options 2 and 3 use the `String.Format` built in functionality of `Console.Writeline`

See the ASCII Printable Code chart for why the magic number is 34: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII